# error after receiving data over TCP/IP connection using Asynchronous socket communication in c#

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, tcp

i have tried to make TCP/IP connection for a server/client application with asynchronous socket communication and it was successful. However, i am not able to display all the message received by client. i have run time error, may i know where is the problem.

```
  private void onreceive(IAsyncResult ar)
        {

                Socket clientsocket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
               int byteread = clientsocket.EndReceive(ar);
                data msgreceived = new data(byteData,byteread);
                data msgtosend = new data();

                byte[] message;

                ClientInfo clientinfo = new ClientInfo();
                clientinfo.socket = clientsocket;
                IPEndPoint remote = clientsocket.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
                remoteip = remote.Address;
                clientinfo.IMEI = msgreceived.IMEI;
                clientlist.Add(clientinfo);
                msgtosend.strMessage = "client with ip address " + remoteip + " with this IMEI " + clientinfo.IMEI;
                txtLog.Text += msgreceived.strMessage + "\r\n";

                if (clientinfo.socket.Connected == true)
                {
                   clientsocket.BeginReceive(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(onreceive), clientsocket);

                }}
```

in data class:

```
     public data(byte[] Data, int msglen)
    {
        //int imeilen = BitConverter.ToInt32(Data, 0);
        //int msglen = BitConverter.ToInt32(Data, 4);

       //if (imeilen > 0)
          // this.IMEI = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Data, 8, imeilen);
        //else this.IMEI = "unknown";
        if (msglen > 0)
            this.strMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Data,0, msglen);
        else
            this.strMessage = "no message";
    }
```

Comment: firstly was the length of array of my data, and then after i fix that , it was on   txtLog.Text += msgreceived.strMessage + "\r\n"; which taking error of accessing another thread, i don't see, accessing different thread actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are somehow magically expecting to know when you have received a "message" despite not even having decided what a message *is* or writing any code to determine whether one has been received.

There is an old saying in the TCP programming community -- nobody is allowed to write any code that uses TCP until they can 100% explain what every word in this true statement means:

"**TCP is a reliable, byte-stream protocol that does not preserve application message boundaries.**"

You have to code to implement a "message". TCP is a byte-stream protocol. If you want to send and receive messages, you'll need to create a protocol that does that.

Start by defining what a message is, how one is delimited, and so on. Then write code to send and receive messages according to your definition. When your `onReceive` function is called, that just means the TCP/IP stack received some bytes -- you need to decide whether that's a message or not by following the rules for a the messaging protocol.